# Where exactly did Wakanda get the Vibranium and how did they get this high-tech?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, black-panther

It is being said throughout *Black Panther* that Wakanda has Vibranium in abundance. In the present day, they've got super high-tech weapons and systems.

But when they show the past *(T'chaka and his brother)* at that time too they had a high-tech jet. So my questions

1. From where exactly did Wakanda get the Vibranium?
2. Back in that time, how did they get the resources to create such high-tech items?

Answer (score 7):

To answer the first part:

- In the distant past, a massive meteorite comprised of the sound-absorbing mineral Vibranium crashed in Wakanda, and was unearthed a generation before the events of the present-day. One of the tribes, lead by Bashenga, it's mightiest warrior, decided to investigate, believing this to be a gift from the gods.

[image: Black panther volume 1_6]

Comment: Yeah, they showed this in the start of the movie.

Comment: I thought they also explained in the movie that due to their access to vibranium they were able to be much more advanced than the rest of the world.

Comment: Yes, with access to Vibranium they are quite advanced than rest of the world, but back in time I doubt how they were able to make such high-tech gadgets.

Comment: Wait, they only got to it 20 years ago? It doesn't seem like that in the movie.

Comment: @HardikT Perhaps the same way everyone else makes such high-tech gadgets? My understanding (although I could easily be wrong) is that the Wakandans have been more advanced than the rest of the world for a long time, and they could have developed the same manufacturing techniques used by everyone else decades or centuries earlier.

Comment: Not sure where you got the idea they only discovered it a generation ago, the movie pretty clearly states they've been developing and advancing for most of their history (and especially throughout the colonial era where they had the technology to remain unadulterated).